# Reuse source ports when connecting to multiple upstream servers?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up reverse proxy meant to serve multiple STUN clients and proxy the communication to multiple upstream servers. I have increased the file descriptors limit for the service so that shouldn't be an issue. My nginx.conf looks more or less like this:

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1000000;
    multi_accept on;
}

stream {

    upstream stun_backend {
        server 192.168.1.10:3478 max_fails=0;
        server 192.168.1.11:3478 max_fails=0;
    }
    server {
    proxy_timeout 30m;
    listen 3478 udp reuseport;
    proxy_pass stun_backend;

  }
}
```

Everything works fine until I get around 28232 (my ephemeral port range is of this size) "udp ESTAB" connections to upstream servers. This is when I start getting the "Resource temporarily unavailable" errors and clients lose ability to contact the stun servers.

I was under the impression that the "IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT" option used by NGINX since version 1.11.2 would help with the problem by reusing existing source ports as long as the destination was different so that the 4-tuple is unique and realistically I should be able to serve `28232 * number_of_upstream_hosts` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Am I mistaken about what this option is meant to do? Is what I'm trying to do even achieveable? If so, how?

Comment: I'm surprised that your setup works. STUN is supposed to receive unaltered connections so it can figure out [what kind of network alteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN#/media/File:STUN_Algorithm3.svg) the client is behind. With a reverse proxy between, this probably makes STUN's work harder.

Comment: @A.B well, in this case STUN's only task is to ensure there's a way for the server to send payload to client when needed (it's app-specific feature). It works fine but unfortunately the NGINX node eventually runs out of free ports to upstream servers. There will be tens of thousands of connections from different clients concurrently so I need to ensure each NGINX node can support as many clients as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation I saw IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT seems to be valid for TCP, I'm not sure if it is valid for UDP.

https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-blog/blob/master/2022-02-connectx/connectx.py#L93-L110

https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-stop-running-out-of-ephemeral-ports-and-start-to-love-long-lived-connections/

I didn't see 'IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT' in udp

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/a52433a04c58821fd95591e474d35995292f1090/src/event/ngx_event_connect.c#L137